# Serilog outputting to console (with ToString() data) and seq (with structured data)

Tags: serilog

I output my logged data to both `Console` and `Seq` sinks. Works great.

When I log a POCO to:

- the `Console` sink, it a long text line with all the properties and the data.
- to `Seq` sink, it's nicely structured so it's easy to search/filter/etc.

Now, is there a way so that when we output the value to the Console sink, it might use the ToString() method of the POCO (instead of -all- the properties) while to Seq it's exactly what it is, now?

I'm just experimenting right now - some classes don't have an overriden ToString() so that means I will just get the class name there.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serilog captures each event property exactly once, and at that point chooses either `ToString()` or structured representation.

It's only later in the logging pipeline that events reach sinks like `Console` and `Seq`, so there's no way for an individual sink (or configuration for a sink) to influence how a particular property value is captured.